# Symmetric products of varieties and projective bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, examples, fibre-bundles, zariski-topology

Given a smooth projective geometrically connected curve $C$, a symmetric product of $C$ has the structure of a projective bundle over the Jacobian of $C$ (e.g. see [Symmetric powers of a curve = projective bundle over Jacobian, and the relative version thereof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68687/symmetric-powers-of-a-curve-projective-bundle-over-jacobian-and-the-relative)).

**Special cases:**

Suppose that $C$ is a hyperelliptic curve defined by $y^2 = f(x)$ for some squarefree polynomial $f$.

1. Is there a simpler method of turning a symmetric power $C^{(n)}$ into a projective bundle (or some other kind of fiber bundle in the Zariski topology) in this case?
2. Are there any other "natural" varieties we can construct using $C$ which have the structure of a projective bundle (or some other kind of fiber bundle in the Zariski topology) for this special case? Do they carry over to curves of the form $y^d = f(x)$ ($f$ *not* a $d^{\text{th}}$ power)?

A nonexample: Consider the map map $C \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ defined by $(x, y) \mapsto x$. Even the map induced on the spaces remaining after removing branch points and their preimages can't be a fiber bundle in the Zariski topology since a "section" would give a map which is not a morphism as it involves $\sqrt{f(x)}$.

**Possible generalizations:**

3. Are there any interesting examples where a symmetric product of a higher dimensional variety has the structure of a projective bundle in the Zariski topology?

Comment: As for 1: I don't know what you mean by "simpler", but the projective bundle structure on $C^{(n)}$ is unique — it is given by the Albanese map.

Comment: Thank you! Does your comment assume the base is the Jacobian of C? I can see what you mean if you assume this, but I'm not sure how this would apply with a different base. The term "simpler" meant possibly something more explicit involving the equation defining the curve than the case of an "arbitrary" curve if possible.